# How to default choose a JTextField in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing

i have a problem for choose by **default** `JTextField` in **java**
i hava tow `JTextField` [`jtextField1` , `jtextField2`]
i need after open app automatically select **`jtextField2`**
but i not found code for this work...

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class DemoTextField
{
    public static void main(String[] test)
    {
        JTextField jtextField1 = new JTextField("jtextField1",15);
        JTextField jtextField2 = new JTextField("jtextField2",15);

        JPanel panle = new JPanel();
        panle.add(jtextField1);
        panle.add(jtextField2);
        
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setSize(250,250);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.add(panle);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        jtextField2.grabFocus(); // <-- Solution
    }
}
```

Compile: `javac DemoTextField.java`
RUN: `java DemoTextField`

[Image Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvAjJ.png)

Comment: Add  `jtextField2.grabFocus();` at the end

Comment: @RaminGsm, don't use grabFocus(). Instead you should use `requestFocusInWindow()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this here so that the question has an answer. As mentioned in the comments above, put `jtextField2.requestFocus();` at the end of your method.

Comment: Use `requestFocusInWindow()`.

Comment: @Abra just tried it. `requestFocusInWindow()` doesn't work, but `requestFocus()` does. Updated the answer to reflect.

Comment: From the _javadoc_ of method `requestFocus()`: Note that the use of this method is discouraged because its behavior is platform dependent. Instead we recommend the use of `requestFocusInWindow()`. If you would like more information on focus, see How to Use the Focus Subsystem, a section in The Java Tutorial.

Comment: Hi @Abra these 2 methods `grabFocus();` and `requestFocusInWindow();` do the same thing.
What is the difference between them?